# GPS-Data from SIM7600E

Tags: gps, gsm, at-command

I need help with my GSM-module. I am using the SIM7600E-4G-HAT module from Waveshare and I am unable to recieve GPS-Data by using the AT-Commands from the manual. The GPS-Antenna is connected to GNSS at the board. I am interfacing the module with the Arduino IDE (Serial-Monitor) and tried the following:

```
14:40:54.375 -> at

14:40:54.375 -> OK
14:40:57.410 -> at+cgps?

14:40:57.410 -> +CGPS: 0,1
14:40:57.410 -> 
14:40:57.410 -> OK
14:41:08.326 -> at+cgps=1,1

14:41:08.326 -> OK
14:41:13.367 -> at+cgpsinfo

14:41:13.367 -> +CGPSINFO: ,,,,,,,,
14:41:13.367 -> 
14:41:13.367 -> OK
14:45:02.691 -> at+cgpsinfo

14:45:02.691 -> +CGPSINFO: ,,,,,,,,
14:45:02.691 -> 
14:45:02.691 -> OK
14:45:04.026 -> at+cgpsinfo

14:45:04.026 -> +CGPSINFO: ,,,,,,,,
14:45:04.026 -> 
14:45:04.026 -> OK
14:45:04.991 -> at+cgpsinfo

14:45:04.991 -> +CGPSINFO: ,,,,,,,,
14:45:04.991 -> 
14:45:04.991 -> OK
```

Previously I was able to get the GPS-Data, but it stopped working somehow. I already thought that either the GPS-Antenna could be broken or I messed up some setting by the AT-Commands.
Here are links to all AT-Commands and to the Manual:

https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7600C/SIM7500_SIM7600%20Series_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.01.pdf
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/6d/SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT-Manual-EN.pdf

Comment: Forgive this question: is the module with is antenna placed on open area outdoor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem. The coaxial cable was defect, so I replaced it and now it works. I don't know the exact reason for this, it could've been due to the HF or no contact.